# Need reference for layer-cake representation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for a reference to a conditional version of the layer-cake representation, i.e.,
$$
\mathbf{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbf{E}\left[1_{X\geq\epsilon}\mid\mathcal{G}\right]d\epsilon.
$$

Comment: How to be sure that $x\mapsto P[X\geqslant x\mid G]$ is regular enough to be almost surely integrable? Recall that each random variable $E[Z\mid G]$ is only defined up to a null event.